# How to update UI from AWS Dynamo DB on a user click event?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a UI that changes on user interaction. For example, there is a button that toggles a "Bookmark". If the user hits to Button when it says "Unbookmarked", the database should reflect this change as well as the UI. The result of this should be a UI that udpates to "Bookmarked" and the database updated to "Bookmarked".

The issue with my code, is that when I press a button to toggle the Bookmark, it only updates the database. When this update happens, the UI doesn't get the latest data from the database.

How can I see the most up to date data from the data base.

*NOTES*

- I am using AWS DynamoDB and AWS AppSync with GraphQL to mutate and read the data
- I am using NextJS and getStaticProps to load the data from Dynamo

Here is my code:

```
export default function Park({park, allSites}) {
  const [selectedCollection, setCollection] = useState(null)

  const userSites = allSites?.filter((p) => p.owner == user?.username)
  const filteredSite = userSites?.filter((p) => p.name == parkCode)[0]

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filteredSite?.bookmarked) {
      setCollection('BOOKMARKED')
    } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == false) {
      setCollection('UNBOOKMARKED')
    } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == null) setCollection(null)
  }, [selectedCollection])
  
  const handleDBQuery = async () => {
    console.log(filteredSite?.bookmarked)
    try {
      user
        ? setCollection('BOOKMARK')
        : alert('Please sign in or create an account')

      const siteInfo = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        name: parkCode,
        bookmarked: true,
        owner: user?.username,
      }
      // A site does not exist, create a new entry
      if (filteredSite == null) {
        await API.graphql({
          query: createSite,
          variables: {input: siteInfo},
          authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
        })
        console.log(`${name} added`)
      }
      // A site exists, update it
      else {
        if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == false) {
          await API.graphql({
            query: updateSite,
            variables: {
              input: {
                id: filteredSite.id,
                bookmarked: true,
                owner: user?.username,
              },
            },
            authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
          })
          setCollection('BOOKMARK')
          console.log(`${name} Bookmarked`)
        } else if (filteredSite?.bookmarked == true) {
          await API.graphql({
            query: updateSite,
            variables: {
              input: {
                id: filteredSite?.id,
                bookmarked: false,
              },
            },
            authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
          })
          setCollection(null)
          console.log(`${name} Unbookmarked`)
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this problem.

PutItem returns a successful HTTP 200 response when you write a record to the table. However, when I try to fetch an item from a read request, Amazon DynamoDB doesn't return the updated record.

This usually happens when an item is finally accessed using a Eventually Consistent Reads immediately after writing it to the table.

getItem basically gives you eventually consistent reads.
To get the latest data as soon as the write request succeeds, set the ConsistentRead parameter to true. This allows for strong consistent reads.

ex)
type Query {
getSites(filter: SiteFilter, ConsistentRead: Boolean): Sites
}

await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getSites,{
filter: SiteFilter, ConsistentRead: true
})
)